# List comprehension is returning "NoneType" TypeError for unknown reason

Tags: python, list-comprehension, typeerror

I'm trying to grab a specific string of a link address from a list of links that I retrieved from a webpage.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Grab table links using url
url = "https://www.epa.gov/automotive-trends/download-automotive-trends-report#Full Report"

html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = [] 
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

auto_rep = [x for x in links if 'report-tables.xlsx' in x][0]
```

The append loop works as intended, resulting in a list of links. However, the auto_rep assignment throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-77ab86ded43b>", line 19, in <module>
    auto_rep = [x for x in links if 'report-tables.xlsx' in x][0]

  File "<ipython-input-3-77ab86ded43b>", line 19, in <listcomp>
    auto_rep = [x for x in links if 'report-tables.xlsx' in x][0]

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I've used this exact format of list comprehension to do the same thing in other contexts, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Check that `link.get('href')` doesn't return `None`.

Comment: Post the full stack trace when posting errors. It's hard to tell where it's complaining.

Comment: Edited the post to include full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the links in your `links` list are None, during the list comprehension you are checking if `'report-tables.xlsx' in x`, since x can be None the `in` check throws an error.

The solution is just to only add the link to the links list if its not None, alternatively, you can use this `[x for x in links if x is not None and 'report-tables.xlsx' in x]`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that links doesn't have None values posted into it. An easy way to do this in Python >= 3.8 is to use an assignment expression:

```py
links = [] 
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if hrefs := link.get('href'):
        links.append(hrefs)
```

For previous python versions you can do:

```
links = [] 
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    hrefs = link.get('href')
    if hrefs:
        links.append(hrefs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`auto_rep = [x for x in links if 'report-tables.xlsx' in str(x)][0]`
Convert all types to strings works.
It can iterate over none types so you need to convert them

Answer (score 1):

Some of the links that it fetches do not have hrefs, so before appending the href to `links`, check if it exists first.

```py
links = [] 
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.get('href'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
```